# Powershell and MySQL parameterized query performance

Tags: mysql, powershell, parameterized-query

I've run into a performance issue with Powershell and generating paramterized queries. I'm pretty sure that I'm going about it wrong and hopefully someone can help.

Here is the problem: inserting 1000 rows (with about 15 columns each) takes around 3 minutes when using parameterized queries. Using non-parameterized batch inserts takes less than a second. The problem seems to lie in how I'm generating the parameters as that is the part of the code that eats most of the time. The looping is killing the performance. The problem wouldn't be a big deal if all I had is 1000 rows to deal with  -however, there are millions.

Here is what I have so far. I've omitted quite a bit for the sake of brevity. But, don't get me wrong  -it certainly works. Its just painfully slow.

```
$values = @() #some big array of values
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ``my_db``.``$table`` (dataseries_code,dataseries_text) VALUES (?,?),(?,?)" #abbreviated for for the sake of sanity

for($i = 0; $i -lt $values.Count; $i++) {
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($i, $values[$i]) #this is the slow part
}

$insertedRows = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Write-Host "$insertedRows"
$sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear()
```

There must be a better way to generate the .Parameters.AddWithValue statement? I took a look at the .AddRange method but couldn't figure how to make it work and if it was even intended for what I'm try to do.

EDIT:
I should have mentioned that I also tried creating the parameters first, and then adding the values. It took 3 minutes to both create the parameters, and 3 minutes to add the values! (see example below). 6 minutes total for 30,000 rows! Something is not right.

I can't help but think that there has to be a faster method to do parameterized inserts?!

```cs
#THIS PIECE WILL ONLY RUN ONCE
#this is where we create the parameters first
for($i = 0; $i -lt @($values).Count; $i++) {
    $command.Parameters.Add((New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter($i[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter]::VarChar))) | out-null
}

#THIS PIECE WILL RUN MULTIPLE TIME
#and this is where we add the values
for($i = 0; $i -lt @($values).Count; $i++) {
    $command.Parameters[$i].Value = $values[$i] | Out-Null
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: IMO you shouldn't use such queries, they simply are decreasing your performance. Instead you may want to use batch query or multiple simple `insert` statements.

Comment: I disagree. Parameterized queries allow you to avoid SQL injection. And, like I mentioned, regular batch inserts perform fine.

Comment: You should try 1000 singular `insert` statements instead of one big statement with 2000 parameters. Such big parameter list may slow down your query and prevent your server from caching the query.

Answer (score 0):

What about building the command object and adding the parameters, then looping through the values.

Instead of clearing the parameters each time, you could just change the value.  That would avoid a lot of object creation/disposal.

Comment: Hi Mike. Good point  -I forgot that I already tried that and ran into the same issue. It took 3 minutes for each the creation of params and adding values to them.  I'm perplexed why something so fundamental would perform so poorly. Bulk inserts and prepared statements aren't exactly new features.

Comment: @Jeremy, your code does not use the real [MS SQL Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx). I'd suppose that your case with many parameters in parametrized query was not optimized by SQL team.

Comment: The question was about MySQL, not MSSQL.

Comment: @ForNeVeR...it was taking 3 minutes to set 15 values?  You did say 1000 rows with 15 columns, correct?  Can you edit the post to show creating the parameters once and setting the values for each row?

Comment: @Mike  -so, maybe this is where I am going wrong... I have been doing 1000 row inserts (15 columns per row). In a separate part of the script I create the value place holders: (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) x 1000. This part is sub-second. Then I go into the parts (see code from question) that add the parameters  -the part that takes forever.

Comment: @Mike  -the second block of code up at the top shows the two loops that I tried: one loop for creating the parameters, and the second loop for adding the values.

Comment: @ForNeVeR has the right idea in his comment on the post.  You need to write a single insert statement with placeholders for the 15 columns.  You will only be creating 15 parameter objects.  Then loop through the values 15 at a time and run the insert with those values.  This should be a lot faster.